# Trigonometry equation $\cos(x)-\cos(2x)+\cos(3x)=0$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve this equation , but i get different answers from the book. 
Can someone help me please?
How to solve

$\cos(x)-\cos(2x)+\cos(3x)=0$

My answers is : $x=45^\circ+90^\circ k$, 
$x=\pm\frac{1}{2} +360^\circ k$

Book's answer:  $\pm60^\circ+360^\circ k$ , $45^\circ+90^\circ k$

Comment: Do you really mean $x=\pm (-0.5)+360k$? I suspect you got confused and did not mean $x=\pm 0.5$ but rather $\cos x=\pm 0.5$ which would fit the given solution $x=\pm 60+360k$, right?

Comment: Yeah .. Thank u . This was my mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice, $$\cos x-\cos 2x+\cos 3x=0$$ $$(\cos x+\cos 3x)-\cos 2x=0$$
$$2\cos\left(\frac{x+3x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-3x}{2}\right)-\cos 2x=0$$

$$2\cos 2x\cos x-\cos 2x=0$$
$$\cos 2x(2\cos x-1)=0 $$
Now, solving for $x$ as follows 
$$\cos 2x=0\implies 2x=(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$$$$x=(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{4}$$$$  \color{red}{x=90^\circ k+45^\circ}$$
or  $$2\cos x-1=0$$$$ \cos x=\frac{1}{2}=\cos \frac{\pi}{3}$$
$$x=2k\pi\pm\frac{\pi}{3}$$$$\color{red}{x=360^\circ k\pm 60^\circ}$$
Where, $\color{blue}{k}$ is any integer

Answer (score 1):

First we need to simplify $\cos(x)-\cos(2x)+\cos(3x)=0$.

$1-2\cos(x)-2\cos^2(x)+4\cos^3(x)=0$

$(2\cos(x)-1)(2\cos^2(x)-1)=0$

Split to two equations:

$2\cos(x)-1=0$ or $2\cos^2(x)-1=0$

And it's easy to solve:

$x=\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi C_1$ ;

$x=\frac{5 \pi }{3}+2\pi C_2$ ;

$x=\frac{\pi}{4}+2 \pi C_3$ ;

$x=\frac{7\pi}{4}+2 \pi C_4$.

$C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4 \in \mathbb{Z} $